# I accidentally dropped my kodak m35 camera and the film count reset to S again

Tags: 35mm, film-cameras

I own a kodak m35 camera and I accidentally dropped it. The film count reset to S again. I already took pics beforehand. Will I lose the pictures I’ve taken? or Do I need to rewind the film and send it for processing already? Should I take pictures and wait for the roll to end?

Comment: Did the back pop open? Even a little?

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: The pictures already taken and the next picture might be at risk, but after that everything should be okay, only be careful when advancing the film.

The film will most likely still be in the same position (the M35 seems to be a manual-wind camera without any motoric film advancing or rewinding), so you can continue from there.

You can take photos normally, only the indicator doesn't warn you when the film ends. So you have to be careful when advancing the film. As soon as you feel some resistance, the film is at its end, and you should rewind. Trying to advance any further might rip the film from the reel inside the cartridge, and you will no longer be able to rewind, effectively losing the film.

As MichaelC pointed out, if the back opened when dropping the camera, if even for a split second, the photos you've taken so far might be lost because of exposing the film to daylight. This will also affect the next picture position, as the relevant film area has already partially left the protecting cartridge. So, the next photo might be lost as well.